# How to prove that the definitions of $MA_{\kappa}$ and $FA_{\kappa}(ccc)$ are equivalents

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to write down the steps which every basic set theory book usually just assume, which is the equivalence between the statements below (where $\Gamma$ is the family of posets which are ccc).

> (I) $MA_{\kappa}$: Given a non-empty ccc poset $\mathbb{P}$ and a family $\{D_{\alpha}: \alpha <\kappa\}$ of dense subsets of $\mathbb{P}$, there exists a filter $G$ with $G\cap D_{\alpha}\not = \emptyset$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

> (II) $FA_{\kappa}(\Gamma)$: Given a poset $\mathbb{P}$ and a family $\{I_{\alpha}: \alpha <\kappa\}$ of maximal antichains of $\mathbb{P}$, there exists a filter $G$ with $G\cap I_{\alpha}\not = \emptyset$ for all $\alpha<\kappa$.

Of course we just have to "translate" dense into maximal antichains and vice versa. I could do (I) $\implies$ (II) closing downwards the given antichains to get $\kappa$ dense subsets and apply $MA_{\kappa}$.

But on (II) $\implies$ (I) I couldn't produce a maximal antichain from the given dense subsets. I tried to set $I_{\alpha}=\{p\in D_{\alpha}: \forall q\in D_{\alpha} (q\not=p \implies q \perp p)\}$, but this antichain does not need to be maximal.

Could you help me? I don't know if it is actually simpler than what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that you can do by recursion:

> Suppose that $\Bbb P$ is a forcing notion and $D$ is a dense open set, then there is a maximal antichain $A\subseteq D$.

The proof is easy. By recursion, construct a sequence of antichains: enumerate $D=\{p_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}$ for some $\lambda$, then pick the least point you can add to your antichain, and take unions at limit stages. By exhaustion, this must stabilise at some point, which means we have a maximal antichain.

In the ccc case we stabilise after countably many steps, of course. But the above is a general fact about forcing and dense open sets (at least as far as assuming the axiom of choice holds).

Now, by enumerating the entire forcing notion, given a family of dense open sets, we can uniformly and easily construct a family of maximal antichains contained in the dense open sets.

Comment: what means 'the least point I can add' if $\mathbb{P}$ doesn't need to have minimal elements?

Comment: also, I can get the "by exhaustion" argument, but I couldn't put it into words, I'd be grateful if you could explain it a bit more

Comment: Least in the enumeration, of course. The exhaustion argument simply means that by the point you stabilise one of two things must have happened: (1) you ran out of points to add, so your antichain is maximal by definition; or (2) you ran out of ordinals and $D$ (or $\Bbb P$) is a proper class.

Comment: so your argument doesn't apply if $D$ is a proper class?

Comment: Well. If $\Bbb P$ is a forcing notion, then it is a set, so every subclass of it is again a set.

Comment: Let me add that while the argument will work, under some reasonable constraints, with class forcing, class forcing can get much more destructive and crazy. It's an interesting subject, but it's worth putting it aside until the basics of forcing are firm in place. Same reason we don't teach toddlers how to fly airplanes.